# Sitecore NullReferenceException when saving the layout page

Tags: sitecore

I have got a NullReferenceException but when i'm trying to save the Layout page. 
I'm using the Email Campaing Manager.
I have built a Layout page (ASPX) which contains several placeholder linked to custom Sub Layout (ASCX)

After adding those Sublayout form via the Email manager ("Add to Here"), I m clicking on the save button and receiving the error message:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.MessageRelationsCorrector.ReplaceItemPaths(LayoutDefinition layout) +164
   Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.MessageRelationsCorrector.CorrectItemRelations(WebPageMail message) +236
   Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Pipelines.CorrectMessageRelations.Process(SaveArgs args) +268

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct&amp; sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +0
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +72
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +251
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +28
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Processor.Invoke(PipelineArgs args) +262
   Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline) +225
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Resume() +39
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.DoStart(PipelineArgs args) +115
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic) +133
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args) +32
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.Save.Execute(CommandContext context) +669
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Dispatcher.Dispatch(Message message, CommandContext context) +62
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Dispatcher.Dispatch(Message message, Item[] items) +110
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Dispatcher.Dispatch(Message message, Item item) +78
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbonForm.HandleMessage(Message message) +429
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.Execute(CommandContext context) +447
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.Dispatch(String command) +143
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RaiseEvent() +108
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +624
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbon.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +103
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496
```

Do you know what could be the reason ? If not, how can i debug those kind of error?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in you development environment?

Comment: Start by removing sublayouts one by one and see if that removes the error. Once you know which sublayout is causing the problem, investigate in code to ensure you have all the null checks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this issue is related to a newly registered bug in the ECM module and I suspect it may have been you who put the original ticket in since the time frames match.  However, if it wasn't you or in the interest of passing this along to others who may be experiencing this issue, in order to get around this, you'll need to put a ticket in to Sitecore support.  There is an initial hotfix that if they find that your issue is the same or related, they can provide you the hotfix.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, I created a ticket and asked the sitecore support. They provided me a workaround, first I didn't define all the datasource of my Sub Layout. Second, the presentation of my newsletter was not correctly defined. I'm waiting for more information regarding a hotfix. Thank you.